# picasso update token for singleton instance

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso "`the below code`" for image loading in my application
 and its work fine till the token get expire,

and when im getting new token im trying to call `ConfigurePicasso` again to update the token

but i get exception `Singleton instance already exists` its there another way to update the token for the singleton instance?.

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ConfigurePicasso(this);
}

    public static void ConfigurePicasso(Context context){
        try {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(ConfigurationRow.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).getAuthToken())) {
                OkHttpClient picassoClient = new OkHttpClient();
                picassoClient.interceptors().add(new TokenInterceptor(ConfigurationRow.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).getAuthToken()));
                File Cachefile = CacheUtils.CacheDir(context.getApplicationContext());
                picassoClient.setCache(new com.squareup.okhttp.Cache(Cachefile, CacheUtils.CacheSize(Cachefile)));
                Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context.getApplicationContext()).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {

                    }
                }).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(picassoClient)).build();
                Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `TokenInterceptor` mutable and hold a reference to it where you want. Set the token on it when necessary.

Something like:

```
final class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  private volatile String someAuthToken = null;

  void setSomeAuthToken(String someAuthToken) {
    this.someAuthToken = someAuthToken;
  }

  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("some-auth-header", someAuthToken).build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: how to implement that ?

Comment: @steevoo It looks like you have the basics ready to go; was there something specific that I can clear up?